# How to forward host traffic to more than one container?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a windows machine. I am running ubuntu using the virtual box on top of it. From windows, I am sending certain information to ubuntu over UDP on a specific port. I am running multiple Docker containers in ubuntu. I want to forward this data to all the containers from ubuntu. Could someone please specify a method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to my question.

I have written a script in python which listens on the specified port and broadcasts it over the docker network. Every container created on that network receives it.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your own answer, you could use nginx to achieve such behavior. Dont need to rewrite what is already implemented but since your script work's i guess you will stick with your solution. Consider this answer mainly for future reader's therefore.